# What could cause BSOD to stuck at 0% resulting no memory dump?

Tags: bsod, minidumps

**Hardware diagnosis:**

Prime95: Passed

FurMark: Passed

Memtest86: Passed

Chkdsk: passed

**Software diagnosis:**

sfc: passed and

DISM: passed

Steam game file verily: passed

**Occurrence of BSOD:**

Randomly appears while playing game Zombie Army 4.

**BSOD timeline:**

1:game freeze  2:game crush 3:explorer freeze 4:**BSOD Critical Process Died** and stucked at 0% memory dump.

**Since the BSOD gives no dump, it's impossible to troubleshoot.**

The only piece of information I can retrieve is that the BSOD happened **AFTER** the game crushed.

**Thanks in advance !**

Answer (score 0):

The principal cause is that the pagefile is too small to contain the crash.
It should be at least the size of the RAM.

For checking the pagefile settings, see the article
[How to Manage Virtual Memory Pagefile in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/77692-manage-virtual-memory-pagefile-windows-10-a.html)
.

Note that some types of crash are too destructive for Windows to create the
crash dump.

Search also for relevant error messages in the Event Viewer.

Disk errors are also a possibility. Run `chkdsk` and check the SMART
info of the system disk.

Comment: I only selected minidump, which is only 256K. Also, Ctr+Scroll crash successfully produced a minidump.

Comment: Minidump is enough for analyzing.